# Python matching keys in list of dicitonaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries, with sub dictionaries data:

```
data2 = [
    {"dep": None},
    {"dep": {
            "eid": "b3ca7ddc-0d0b-4932-816b-e74040a770ec",
            "nid": "fae15b05-e869-4403-ae80-6e8892a9dbde",
        }
    },
    {"dep": None},
    {"dep": {
            "eid": "c3bcaef7-e3b0-40b6-8ad6-cbdb35cd18ed",
            "nid": "6a79c93f-286c-4133-b620-66d35389480f",
        }
    },
]
```

And I have a match key:

```
match_key = "b3ca7ddc-0d0b-4932-816b-e74040a770ec"
```

And I want to see if any sub dictionaries of each "dep" key in data2 have an eid that matches my match_key.  I'm trying the following, but I get a TypeError: string indices must be integers - where am I going wrong?

**My Code**

```
matches = [
            d["eid"]
            for item in data2
            if item["dep"]
            for d in item["dep"]
            if d["eid"] == match_key
        ]
```

So matches should return:

```
["b3ca7ddc-0d0b-4932-816b-e74040a770ec"]
```

Meaning it found this id in data2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over a dictionary, each iteration gives you a *key* from the dictionary.

So `d["eid"]` is actually `"eid"["eid"]`, which is an invalid expression. That's why Python raises the following exception:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Also, the expression `d["eid"]` assumes that every `d` contains the `eid` key. If it doesn't, Python will raise a `KeyError`.

If you don't know for sure that "eid" is a valid key in the dictionary, prefer using  the [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method instead.

```
matches = [
    v
    for item in data2
    if item.get("dep")  # Is there a key called dep, and it has a non-falsy value in it
    for k, v in item["dep"].items()  # Iterate over the dictionary items
    if k == "eid" and v == match_key
]
```

You can do even better by directly accessing the value of `eid` key:

```
matches = [
    d["dep"]["eid"]
    for d in data2
    if d.get("dep") and d["dep"].get("eid") == match_key
]
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works nicely.  There will always be an eid key in the sub dictionary when "dep" is populated.